# Prove that the minimal set of functions for which these properties hold are step functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

(H. Priestley - Introduction to Integration - Exercise 4.3)

> Define the class $\mathbb L$ of integrable functions for which the following $Basic Properties$ hold:
>
>
> (1) **Building Block**: $ \forall a,b \in \mathbb R $ the characteristic function is integrable and $\int \chi_{[a,b]} := (b-a)$
>
> (2) **Linearity**: if $f,g$ are integrable and $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ then $f+ \lambda g$ is integrable and $\int (f+\lambda g)=\int f + \lambda \int g$
>
> (3) **Positivity**: if $f$ is integrable then $f(x) \ge 0 \  \forall x \implies \int f \ge 0$
>
> (4) **Modulus property**: if $f$ is integrable then so is $|f|$
>
>
> Prove that the class of step functions is the minimal set of functions in $\mathbb L$ for which these properties hold.

Normally I give an attempt at the answer but in this case, I have no clue how to even start ... I am not even sure I understand what a $minimal \  set$ of functions is.

Comment: The usual way of introducing Lebesque integral is to define it for step functions (and check the properties above for them) and then introduce the set $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ of Lebesgue integrable functions that are limits of a sequences of step functions. Every such function itself is an equivalence class under equality almost everywhere (we can add or substract any function that is =0 a. e.). Thus, $L^1$'s norm and metric are norm and metric on the factorspace $\mathcal{L}^1=L^1(R)/\mathcal{N}$, where $\mathcal{N}$ is a space of functions, that are =0 a.e. (This distinction is usually ignored).

Comment: Maybe this can help here.

Comment: It seems, as long as $\mathcal{L}^1$ is a Banach space, the question is to prove that step functions are complete minimal system there.

Comment: thank you very much for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say $S$ is the class of all step functions. Saying that $S$ is the minimal class where properties 1-4 hold means two things:

1. Properties 1-4 hold for the class $S$.
2. If $C$ is a class of functions for which 1-4 hold then $S\subset C$.

So that says you have to do two things. First, show that $S$ satisfies properties 1-4. Second, *assume* that $C$ satisfies 1-4, and then use those properties of $C$ to show that $C$ contains every step function.

Comment: thank you very much I will have a go !